# Get a document from firestore by name

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The firestore docs seem confusing to me. Say I have a set of posts:

```
posts: [{ name: 'Foo' }, { name: 'Bar' }]
```

And I want to get a post with the name `Foo`.

Following this guide: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

It begins with this line: 
`var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");`

I dont 'understand what `.doc("SF")` means. Is `SF` an ID? What if my ID was auto-generated? I want to fetch data using this method:

```
docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
      ...
    }
}
```

But confused about the documentation. What's the best way to `get()` with my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you [understand the Cloud Firestore data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model). It's not the same as Firebase Realtime Database (formerly known as just Firebase).

If the `posts` from your example is a collection with two documents, you can use a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to find a document by `name`:

```
var query = db.collection("posts").where("name", "==", "Foo");
var querySnapshot = await query.get();
```

Now `querySnapshot` will be an array of documents that matched your query.

You need an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for any kind of query, but this one is simple enough that it will be automatically created for you.